# How accurately must I compute the twin prime constant to get the twin prime density?

Tags: asymptotics, computational-mathematics, twin-primes

Let $\pi _{2}(x)$ denote the number of primes $p\leq x$ such that $p+2$ is also prime. Hardy and Littlewood conjectured that

$$
{\displaystyle \pi _{2}(x)\sim 2C_{2}{\frac {x}{(\ln x)^{2}}}\sim 2C_{2}\int _{2}^{x}{dt \over (\ln t)^{2}}},
$$

where

$$
{\displaystyle C_{2}=\prod _{\textstyle {p\;{\rm {prime}} \atop p\geq 3}}\left(1-{\frac {1}{(p-1)^{2}}}\right)\approx 0.660161815846869573927812110014\dots }.
$$

I want to numerically study this density, so I implemented some C++ code that computes the above value for $\pi_2(x)$. However, before launching any computations I want to make sure that I set everything up correctly. In particular, I am unsure about what precision I should use for $C_2$, i.e., the twin-prime constant, in function of my input $x$.

In other words, how many primes should I include within the product for $C_2$ so that I get the correct expected conjectured density for $\pi_2(x)$? For example, if I want to calculate the conjectured density for $\pi_2(10^5)$, should I include all primes $\leq 10^5$ in the product for $C_2$?

Comment: The number of digits of $C_2$ given in the problem will be more than accurate enough for any $x$ you can reach numerically.  Sub-leading terms in the asymptotic form are going to contribute much earlier than the 30th significant figure.

Comment: @mjqxxxx Thank you for your comment. Can you give a more detailed answer, in terms of $x$? For instance, how many primes should I consider in the product for $\pi_2(10^x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Calculations using Wolfram Alpha give](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Bprod_(k%3D2)%5E1000%20(1-1%2F(prime(k)-1.0)%5E2)%7D,%20%7Bprod_(k%3D2)%5E10000%20(1-1%2F(prime(k)-1.0)%5E2)%7D,%20%7Bprod_(k%3D2)%5E100000%20(1-1%2F(prime(k)-1.0)%5E2)%7D)
$$C_2(1000)=0.66017,\quad C_2(10000) = 0.660162,\quad C_2(100000) = 0.660162.$$
I think this gives information about accuracy.

On the other hand,
$$\int_2^x \dfrac{dt}{\ln^2 t} =  \mathrm{li}(x) - \mathrm{li}(2) - \dfrac x{\ln x} + \dfrac 2{\ln2}$$
(see also [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_2%5Ex%20dt%2Fln%5E2%20t)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I fail to see how this answers my question: " *how many primes should I include within the product for C2 so that I get the correct expected conjectured density for $π2(x)$*"; in function of $x$?

Comment: @Klangen What about the range of x?

Comment: If I want to calculate the conjectured density for $π_2(10^5)$, should I include all primes $≤10^5$ in the product for $C_2$?

Comment: @Klangen Then you will have more than 6D

Comment: @Klangen On the other hand, all primes < 10000 also gives 6D.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "6D"?

Comment: @Klangen 1) By comparing with the exact value; 2) By comparing $C_2(10^4)$ and $C_2(10^5).$
Do you need another proof? It can be obtained too.

Comment: *Can you please explain what you mean by "6D"?*

Comment: @Klangen Six right decimal digits

Comment: Thank you. So if I want to calculate the conjectured density for $π_2(10^x)$, I need to include at least all primes $≤10^x$ in the product for $C_2$, is that correct?

Comment: @Klangen I think that if the accuracy $6D$ satisfies then all primes $\leq 10^4$ will be sufficiently for the production.